# How to train and evaluate model based on inner ordering of data subsets?

Tags: dataset, machine-learning-model, training, model-evaluations

I've got a problem which I don't know how to frame properly (what techniques to use, what data structure, etc).

---

Here's a rough definition of it:

```
X = [x1, x2, ..., xn], n ~= 10
where X is a data point, and xi represent its features.

D = [X1, X2, ..., Xm], m ~= 3000
where D is the full dataset, ordered w.r.t. T

T = [t1, t2, ..., tm]
where T is the vector of ground truth values.
```

The tricky part is the training/evaluation, here's how I need it to be structured:

```
S = [G1, G2, ..., Gk], k < m
where S is the structured dataset, and Gi is a subset of D with no intersection with any other Gi.
```

So for example:

```
G1 = [X1, X4, X13, ..., Xj], j < m
G2 = [X3, X9, X12, ..., ]
...
```

For each `Gi`, the model performs well if it outputs the data in the same order (scalar result computed with mean square of differences of positions in the group).
This should give the following result:

```
Y = [y1, y2, ..., yk]
where yi is the scalar result of the model for Gi, and so on.
```

And finally, by aggregating `Y`, I'd get a global scalar for the performance of the model.

---

Any tips on how to approach this ? I use python if you can guide to specific solutions, but really just knowing what techniques to use could help me a lot.

Comment: this is part of cross-validation procedures, check it out

Comment: @NikosM. Is it really though ? Because how I understand it is that `S` essentially becomes the input to the model (everything up to `S` being preprocessing). So one datapoint in this scenario is a full subset `Gi`, no ? And cross-validation would be to train on some of these subsets, and cross-validate with other subsets ? I'm very uncertain about what the input to the model should be given the subset ordering metric I'm looking to optimize.

Comment: It seems to me like cross-validation, but maybe you should post the original problem and let people see